# Is Homeo$(X)$ a $G_\delta$ subset of $C(X,X)$?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, polish-spaces

I need to prove that if $X$ is a compact Polish space, then $Homeo(X)$ (the set of homeomorphisms from $X$ to $X$) is a $G_\delta$ subset of $C(X,X)$ (the space of continuous functions with de topology given by the uniform convergence metric i.e. $d_{\infty}(f,g)=\sup_{x \in X}\{d_X(f(x),g(x))\}$) and hence is a Polish space.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reverse engineering the oscillation function?

Comment: Actually it seems easier to show directly that the group of homeomorphisms is complete, and then refer to e.g. Thm.3.11 in Kechris' Classical Descriptive Set Theory (p.17), which says that a subspace of a Polish space is Polish iff $G_\delta$. For this the supremum metric will not work (homeo group is neither open nor closed w/r/t the metric; e.g. consider the case $X=[0,1]$), but the metric $d(f,g)=d_\infty(f,g)+d_\infty(f^{-1},g^{-1})$ will.